# Two dimentional array in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get a two dimensional array in Javascript, but I have a json and from that I am trying to populate a 2D array. My code is here:

```
jQuery.each(data.data, function(key,val){
        survey_sec_id_arr.push(val.section_id);
        survey_question_id_arr.push(val.section_id);
        jQuery.each(val, function(key1,val1){
            if(key1!="section_id" && key1!="section_name"){ 
                survey_question_id_arr[val.section_id].push(val1.question_id);
            }
        });
});
console.log(survey_question_id_arr);
```

So here the error in firebug is:

> `TypeError: survey_question_id_arr[val.section_id] is undefined`

What is going wrong?

Comment: Please show the values of `survey_question_id_arr`, `data `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you loop is not correct. You add all of those elements via push so your array looks like

```
survey_question_id_arr = array( [0] => val.section_id, [1] => val.section_id...)
```

then you try to get an element of this array via

```
//returns undefined
survey_question_id_arr[val.section_id]

//should return a value
val.section_id[0]
```

fix:

```
survey_question_id_arr[val.section_id].push(val1.question_id)
```

i think this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can Push a value in an array.

I guess Over here your var `val.section_id` is not an array. We can push values in an array. So first initialize it as Empty array like:

```
survey_question_id_arr[val.section_id] = [];
```

(Declare it before inner loop)

then try pushing value in it.

```
survey_question_id_arr[val.section_id].push(val1.question_id)
```

Hope it helps.